# Msg 4145, Level 15, An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'. error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I was trying to show the max of the alias `[totalmonthly]`, I tried to put `{SUM(([Price]-[CostToMake])* MonthlySales)}` but still nothing showed up. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT      Name, 
            SUM(([Price]-[CostToMake])* MonthlySales) AS TotalMonthly
FROM        SalesTable
GROUP BY    Name
HAVING      MAX(TotalMonthly)
```

And I am getting error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15,
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TOP (1)` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) Name, 
       SUM(([Price]-[CostToMake])* MonthlySales) AS TotalMonthly
FROM SalesTable
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY TotalMonthly DESC;
```

I assume that your query is generating an error rather than the wrong results.